# OpenCV Decompose projection matrix

Tags: python, opencv, computer-vision

I got confused with the outputs of opencv decomposeProjectionMatrix function.

I have the projection matrix and the camera matrix "K" and I want to get the translation vector "t"and the Rotation matrix "R" from the projection matrix

As I know the projection matrix of dimension 3*4 = K[R|t] in which "t" is a 3*1 vector

cv2.decomposeProjectionMatrix returns R with dimension 3*3  which is correct but the transVect returned is of dimension 4*1 not 3*1

My question is how to get back the projection matrix from the function outputs?

documentation: https://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/calib3d/doc/camera_calibration_and_3d_reconstruction.html

Answer (score 2):

You have to normalise it by the last number: `t = t[:3] / t[3]`

But for some reason, you need to multiply it by -1.
Here is my example:

```
k = np.array([[631,   0, 384],
              [  0, 631, 288],
              [  0,   0,   1]])
r = np.array([[-0.30164902,  0.68282439, -0.66540117],
              [-0.63417301,  0.37743435,  0.67480953],
              [ 0.71192167,  0.6255351 ,  0.3191761 ]])
t = np.array([ 3.75082481, -1.18089565,  1.06138781])

C = np.eye(4)
C[:3, :3] = k @ r
C[:3, 3] = k @ r @ t

out = cv2.decomposeProjectionMatrix(C[:3, :])
```

and `out` gives the following:

```
out[0]:
array([[631.,  -0., 384.],
       [  0., 631., 288.],
       [  0.,   0.,   1.]])
out[1]:
array([[-0.30164902,  0.68282439, -0.66540117],
       [-0.63417301,  0.37743435,  0.67480953],
       [ 0.71192167,  0.6255351 ,  0.3191761 ]])
out[2]:
array([[-0.89432836],
       [ 0.28156699],
       [-0.25307213],
       [ 0.23843512]])
```

If you apply the normalisation, you get:

```
array([[-3.75082481],
       [ 1.18089565],
       [-1.06138781]])
```

what is actually a `-t`.
However `np.linalg.inv(C[:3, :3]) @ C[:3, 3]` gives the correct result

```
array([ 3.75082481, -1.18089565,  1.06138781])
```

Answer (score 0):

`C = K[R|t] = K(R|Rt) = (KR|KRt) = (M | Mt)`
The fourth column of C is c4.

```
Mt = c4.
t = M^(-1)c4
```

ref [https://www.ics.uci.edu/~majumder/vispercep/cameracalib.pdf](https://www.ics.uci.edu/%7Emajumder/vispercep/cameracalib.pdf)